# Making a GET request using an Arduino Uno & Ciao

Tags: php, rest, arduino, wifi, arduino-uno

I'm using an Arduino Uno Wifi and I want to send sensor data from my Uno to a PHP-Script, which saves the data into a MySQL Database. For the GET request I'm using the Ciao.write() function from the UnoWiFiDevEd.h library, since I haven't figured out another possible way (without using a shield).

This is how my Arduino Code looks like:

```
#include <UnoWiFiDevEd.h>

void setup() {
  char* connector = "rest";
  char* server = "myserver/src/add_data.php?";
  char* method = "GET";
  String resource = "humidity=11&&temperature=22";

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ciao.begin();

  doRequest(connector, server, resource, method);
}

void loop() {

}

void doRequest(char* conn, char* server, String command, char* method) {
  CiaoData data = Ciao.write(conn, server, command, method);
  if(!data.isEmpty()){
    Serial.println("Success");
  } else {
    Serial.println("FAILED");
  }  
}
```

And this is my PHP script (get_data.php)

```
<?php
    // Connect to MySQL
    include("dbconnect.php");

    // Prepare the SQL statement
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO arduino_data (Humidity, Temperature) VALUES ('".$_GET["humidity"]."', '".$_GET["temperature"]."')";

    // Execute SQL statement
    mysql_query($SQL);
?>
```

If I'm using a browser and write "myserver/src/add_data.php?humidity=60&&temperature=22" into the url bar, everything works just fine.

I think I might misunderstand how this Ciao.write works, even though I looked in the code (in the CiaoData PassThroughRead function) and thought I specified everything correct. The [documentation](http://www.arduino.org/learning/reference/ciao-write) is no help at all.

As reference I used this [tutorial](http://www.arduino.org/learning/tutorials/boards-tutorials/restclient) which is fully working somehow.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, but you have SQL-Injection in the `$SQL` variable through both GET parameters

Comment: You mean as a security flaw? Right now it's just an workaround until I figured out a better way to write sensor data directly from my Arduino Uno Wifi into a MySQL database

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the method POST not GET. I had the exact issue.